# Отображение данных с помощью SwingWorker

Tags: java, swing, jframe

У меня идут данные с телефона на компьютер и отображаются в окне JFrame. Решил попробовать сделать с `SwingWorker`, чтобы он подгружал новые данные, при этом не открывая новые окна. Сейчас это выглядит в виде: пришел ответ - открывается новое окно с подгруженными данными, при этом старое окно остается открытым до конца работы программы. Написал реализацию метода `doInBackground()`, но уверен, что сделал все неправильно. Не могли бы вы помочь разобраться, как это лучше всего реализовать, а также исправить мой метод `doInBackground()`. Данные, при поступлении, записываются в HashMap и далее передаются в класс SimpleTableDemo.Заранее спасибо.

```
public class SimpleTableDemo extends JFrame {
    private static final String[] columnNames = { "Судья", "Ответ" };
    private final JTable table;
    private static SwingWorker swingWorker;

    public SimpleTableDemo() {
        super("Test");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 0));
        table = new JTable(new Object[0][0], columnNames) {
            @Override
            public Class getColumnClass(int column) {
                switch (column) {
                    case 1:
                        return String.class;
                    default:
                        return Object.class;
                }
            }

            @Override
            public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int col) {
                return false;
            }
        };

        table.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(new Dimension(500, 80));
        table.setFillsViewportHeight(true);
        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(table);
        add(scrollPane);
        pack();
        setVisible(true);

        swingWorker = new SwingWorker() {
            @Override
            protected Object doInBackground() throws Exception {
                Map<Object,String> newMap = new HashMap<Object, String>();
                newMap = Server.getAnswerMap();
                return newMap;
            }
        };
    }

    public void setData(Map<Object,String> map) {
        Object[][] data = map.entrySet()
                .stream()
                .map(e -> new Object[] { e.getKey(), e.getValue() })
                .toArray(Object[][]::new);
        table.setModel(new DefaultTableModel(data, columnNames));
    }

    private static void start() {
        SimpleTableDemo demo = new SimpleTableDemo();
        Map<Object,String> map = new HashMap<>();
        demo.setData(map);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(SimpleTableDemo::start);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Что-то вроде:

```
class ServerWorker extends SwingWorker<Void, Map<Object, String>> {
    private SimpleTableDemo window;

    public ServerWorker(SimpleTableDemo windows) {
        this.window = window;
    }

    @Override
    public String doInBackground() {
        while (true) {
            publish(Server.getAnswerMap());
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void process(List<Map<Object, String>> chunks) {
        Map<Object, String> map = chunks.get(chunks.size() - 1);
        window.setData(map);
    }
}

public class SimpleTableDemo extends JFrame {
    ...

    private static void start() {
        SimpleTableDemo demo = new SimpleTableDemo();

        new ServerWorker(demo).execute();
    }

    ...
}
```

Только вместо `while (true)` стоит использовать что-нибудь, позволяющее мягко завершить поток. И метод `setData` - не образец эффективности, поэтому окно может начать тормозить и лагать, если `Server.getAnswerMap()` будет возвращать данные слишком часто.